# Sort posts on custom field AND after that sort on date?

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, sort, date

I'm having trouble to understand customizing the new WP_query. I've found the script below, partly, [here](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-display-the-latest-sticky-posts-in-wordpress/) in order to get the sticky posts.
I've further edited it in order to:

- first get the (sticky) posts with the custom field 'cc_aff_stick_top'
  and order them DESC (high integer - low integer)
- Then DESC sort the sticky other posts (without that custom field) based on date.

Especially showing/sorting the second point, I find confusing. I tried it with

```
'is_not_aff' => array(
         'key' => 'cc_aff_stick_top',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
    ),
```

**Question**

- That seems to be working, but I am pretty sure this is not the right
  way to go. Who can help me out?
- Also, I am wondering why `meta_query` needs to be there. I only want
  to query posts based on the `tax_query`. Is it correct that
  `meta_query`actually does another query of the posts? Is `meta_query`
  required in order to sort on multiple values?
- How can I sort the posts without the CF `cc_aff_stick_top` by date? Adding `'date' => 'DESC'` in the `'orderby' => array` is not working.

**Answer**

Works: `'orderby' => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'date' => 'ASC' )`

Works: Setting `'type' => 'NUMERIC'` in the meta_query, and `'orderby' => array( 'is_aff' => 'DESC', 'date' => 'DESC' )`

The code:

```
    /* Get all sticky posts */
    $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );

    //Get term
    $term = get_queried_object();

    if (!empty($sticky)) {
    /* Sort the stickies with the newest ones at the top */
    rsort( $sticky );

    /* Get the 5 newest stickies (change 5 for a different number) */
    $sticky = array_slice( $sticky, 0, 50 );

    /* Query sticky posts */
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__in' => $sticky, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'post_type' => 'ad_listing', 'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
            array (
                'taxonomy' => 'ad_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $term->slug,
            ),
//Posts with the slug below should be shown everywhere
            array (
                'taxonomy' => 'ad_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'cc-slug',
            )
        ),
        'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        'is_aff' => array(
            'key' => 'cc_aff_stick_top',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
        'is_not_aff' => array(
             'key' => 'cc_aff_stick_top',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ), 
    ),
    'orderby' => array( 
        'is_aff' => 'ASC',
        'is_not_aff' => 'DESC',
    ),
    ) );
    // The Loop
```

Comment: Try changing `'is_not_aff' => 'DESC'` to `'date' => 'DESC'`. That should work. And I think you don't need the `is_not_aff` in the `meta_query`..

Comment: That is not changing the sorting of posts without custom field `'cc_aff_stick_top'`. Also can you explain what `'meta_query'` precisely does? I only want to sort the posts queried based on the `'tax_query'`, but the `'meta_query'` is required to sort posts on multiple values?

Comment: Ok, sorry about that - I did not really notice you want to query for posts that have the `cc_aff_stick_top` meta as well as posts that *don't* have that meta. And yes we use `meta_query` to query for multiple meta, and the keys can be used for sorting the results - e.g. the `'is_aff' => 'DESC'` in your `orderby` arg. But if you add the `'date' => 'DESC'` into that arg, the posts would/should be sorted by the post date after sorting by the `is_aff` and `is_not_aff`.

Comment: And by "add", I mean like this: `'orderby' => array( 'is_aff' => 'DESC', 'is_not_aff' => 'DESC', 'date' => 'DESC' )` - alternatively use `'post_date' => 'DESC',`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your clarification. To be clear; i want to get all sticky posts, done with the `'tax_query'`. Then i want the posts with the custom field `'cc_aff_stick_top'`, to show first. After that the other (sticky) posts need to be shown, ordered by date (DESC). Setting `'is_aff' =>` to `DESC` will cause for the `'cc_aff_stick_top'` posts to show at the bottom. Setting it to `'is_aff' =>` to `ASC` will show the posts on top. However the `'date' => 'DESC'` is still not working fo the 'is_not_aff' posts. It shows the older posts first.

Comment: Have you actually tried with `'orderby' => array( 'is_aff' => 'DESC', 'date' => 'DESC' )` (without the `'is_not_aff' => 'DESC'`)? Also, looking at your `tax_query`, you can combine the queries: `'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => 'ad_cat', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => array( $term->slug, 'cc-slug' ) ) )`

Comment: Yes, tried a lot of those combinations. Sorting by date only works when soley sorting on date; `'orderby' => array( 'date' => 'ASC')`. Strange...

Comment: If the meta `cc_aff_stick_top` has a numeric value, then in your `meta_query`, try adding `'type' => 'NUMERIC',` to the meta query. Refer to the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) for further information on that.

Comment: `'orderby' => array( 
    'meta_value_num' => 'DESC',
 'date' => 'ASC'
),` works!

Comment: Setting `'type'    => 'NUMERIC',` and `'orderby' => array( 
    'is_aff' => 'DESC',
 'date' => 'DESC'
),` works as well!

Comment: Yep, I forgot the `meta_value_num`.. :) But if you're querying for metas with varying value type, you should explicitly set the meta `type`.

Comment: Yes, but in this case i only use the CF `cc_aff_stick_top`, which is numeric and date (but you don't have to specify the type here i guess). So i decided to use: `'orderby' => array( 
    'meta_value_num' => 'DESC',
 'date' => 'DESC'
),` and not set the type for every meta_query, just because this requires less code. Thanks a lot for sticking with me.

Comment: Yes, that's right. And no problem, we're here to help each other.. :) All the best.